# PHP split alternative?

Tags: php

PHP is telling me that split is deprecated, what's the alternative method I should use?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

**[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** is an alternative. However, if you meant to split through a ***regular expression***, the alternative is **[`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split)** instead.

Comment: I disagree - `explode` is not the alternative, since it does not perform the same function as `split`, that is: to split a string *by a regular expression*. For that purpose, use `preg_split`.

Comment: @nickf: That's rightly pointed, i should have added that initially on. Thanks

Comment: In various languages, the `split` method does not always accept regular expressions. In .NET, Python, the `String.Split()` / `str.split()` methods only accept a fixed, literal string as a needle. Thus, `explode` is correct. For those coming from Java, JavaScript, Ruby, `preg_split` might turn out the solution.

Comment: It's compatible with Visual Basic .NET's String.Split(). Nice

Answer (score 22):

`split` is deprecated since it is part of the family of functions which make use of POSIX regular expressions; that entire family is deprecated in favour of the PCRE (`preg_*`) functions.

If you do not need the regular expression functionality, then [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) is a very good choice (and would have been recommended over `split` even if that were not deprecated), if on the other hand you do need to use regular expressions then the PCRE alternate is simply [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split).

Answer (score 17):

- [`preg_split`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) if you need to split by regular expressions.
- [`str_split`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) if you need to split by characters.
- [`explode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) if you need to split by something simple.

Also for the future, if you ever want to know what PHP wants you to use if something is deprecated you can always check out the [function](http://us.php.net/split) in the manual and it will tell you alternatives.

Answer (score 8):

I want to clear here that `preg_split();` is far away from it but `explode();` can be used in similar way as `split();`

following is the comparison between `split();` and `explode();` usage

### How was split() used

```
<?php

$date = "04/30/1973";
list($month, $day, $year) = split('[/.-]', $date);
echo $month; // foo
echo $day; // *
echo $year;

?>
```

URL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

### How explode() can be used

```
<?php

$data = "04/30/1973";
list($month, $day, $year) = explode("/", $data);
echo $month; // foo
echo $day; // *
echo $year;

?>
```

URL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Here is how we can use it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the easier function preg_match instead, It's better and faster than all of the other ones.

```
$var = "<tag>Get this var</tag>";
preg_match("/<tag>(.*)<\/tag>/", $var , $new_var);
echo $new_var['1'];
```

Output: `Get this var`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would use explode or you could use:

`preg_split`

Which is the advised method with PHP 6.
[preg_split Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a string into words, you can use explode() or str_word_count().

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but my code must work on both PHP 5 & PHP 7..

Here is my piece of code, which solved this.. Input a date in dmY format with one of delimiters "/ . -"

```
<?php
function DateToEN($date){
  if ($date!=""){
    list($d, $m, $y) = function_exists("split") ?  split("[/.-]", $date) : preg_split("/[\/\.\-]+/", $date);
    return $y."-".$m."-".$d;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```