# Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated. How to rewrite this statement?

Tags: regex, php, posix-ere

I have the following statement which worked fine before PHP 5.3 using the [`split` function](http://php.net/split):

```
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $min, $sec) = split( '[: -]', $post_timestamp );
```

After upgrading to PHP 5.3, I get the Deprecated warning:

> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated.

I am trying to parse a string with format like:

> 2010-08-10 23:07:58

into its component parts.

Comment: Related: [PHP split alternative? (May 2010)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2813241/367456)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think you want [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

```
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $min, $sec) = preg_split('/[: -]/', $post_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2010-08-10 23:07:58');

$year = $dateTime->format('Y');
$month = $dateTime->format('m');
```

You get the drill...
Depending, on what you're going to do with it, using DateTime object might be more convenient than using six separate variables.

Answer (score 7):

Just try to replace "split" with "explode" the newer version of PHP and MYSQL accept "explode" instead of "split"

Comment: `explode` can't be used in this case because it can be used with only one delimiter symbol. MySQL isn't related to this question at all.

Answer (score 4):

```
var_dump(strptime($post_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'));
```

Comment: +1 I posted preg_split as an answer to the replacement for split, but I would have to agree that if you are parsing a timestamp, you should use functions designed for that with proper handling, etc.

Comment: @Brandon Horsley: the only weird thing of this solution is that year is not absolute, but the years since 1900 :-S so post-processing is needed :-(

Comment: @zerkms Well, than use the "datetime"-type and not timestamps. See Mchl's answer.

Comment: @zerkms That was a reply to your "the only weird thing of this solution is that year is not absolute, but the years since 1900" above. You can pass in user inputs in several formats into the constructor of the PHP DateTime-objects, which are not bound to the 1900-start-year. Example: `new DateTime( '1765-06-13 16:45' )`; you can then use the object methods or the formatted output to access the parts. My fault was, that I thought `strptime` works on a UNIX-timestamp internally, because of that 1900-thingy; but I think that's not true also – I don't know, where this quirk comes from.

Comment: @feeela: oh, right. Feeling like a jerk now :-S I need to be more attentive then :-S (even in cases the answer was given 1.5y ago). Sorry :-(

Comment: @zerkms whoops, I didn't consider the date… ;-)