# Deprecated : Function split() php error

Tags: php, file, function, directory, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated. How to rewrite this statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453915/deprecated-function-split-is-deprecated-how-to-rewrite-this-statement)

I'm getting a Deprecated: function split() is deprecated error on this code.

```
function getFileExt($filename) {
$filename = strtolower($filename) ;
$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;
$n = count($exts)-1;
$exts = $exts[$n];
return $exts;
```

I'm meant to rewrite it or something but I have no idea how!

If somebody could help many thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Comment: and [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173868/how-to-extract-a-file-extension-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function getFileExt($filename) {
    $filename = strtolower($filename) ;
    $exts = explode(".", $filename) ;
    $n = count($exts)-1;
    $exts = $exts[$n];
    return $exts; 
}
```

The same just using explode on the ".".

Answer (score 1):

The function split is a old function. You can use explode to split.

http://www.php.net/explode