# "Function split() is deprecated" in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

```
$stringText = "[TEST-1] test task 1 Created: 06/Apr/11  Updated: 06/Apr/11"; 
$splitArray = split(" ",$stringText);
```

> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\RSS.php on line 27

Why this error happen ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php - please read the docs before asking questions here.

Comment: Please enable `html_errors` and `docref_root` in your php.ini

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP split alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813241/php-split-alternative)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

From the manual

> Warning This function has been
>   DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on
>   this feature is highly discouraged
>
> Note:
>
> As of PHP 5.3.0, the regex extension
>   is deprecated in favor of the PCRE
>   extension. Calling this function will
>   issue an E_DEPRECATED notice. See the
>   list of differences for help on
>   converting to PCRE.

I guess you're supposed to use the alternative `preg_split()`. Or if you're not using a regex, just use `explode`

Answer (score 9):

split has been replaced with `explode`, see http://php.net/explode for more information. Works the same as split, but split is 'deprecated' basically means that is a old function that shouldn't be used anymore, and is not likely to be in later versions of php.

Comment: Actually, `split` and `explode` are a bit different. `explode` doesn't support regex, so the replacement function would be `preg_split`

Answer (score 6):

Use following explode function:

```
$command = explode(" ", $tag[1]);
```

This is the standard solution for this case.
Its Perfectly working.

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) says about it. And the docs also say which functions should be used instead of this:

1. [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)
2. [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
3. [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 1):

Because the function has been deprecated? You can customize the error_reporting level to not log / display the depreciated errors. But it would be more prudent to just correct the issue (IE use explode instead for the simple split you are doing above.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom function for old codes:

```
if (!function_exists('split')) {
    function split($pattern, $subject, $limit=-1, $flags=0){
        return preg_split($pattern, $subject, $limit, $flags);
    }
}
```