# Split() deprecated

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP split alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813241/php-split-alternative)

```
 // Successful geocode
$geocode_pending = false;
$coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
$coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
// Format: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
 $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];
$lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];
```

Hello People, this is a part of my geolocation code. I try to change a stored adress into a lat/long and than save the lat/long back in the database. 
They use the split function to put a string in an array but since php 5.3.0 the function is deprecated.
Anyone has a solution for this?

Thank you

EDIT:

When i use this

```
$coordinatesSplit = preg_split(",", $coordinates);
```

I receive following error

> preg_split() [function.preg-split]:
>   No ending delimiter

**LAST edit**
When i add something to the database, the long/late are automatically saved to. But when i want to add for example the 6th adress in the database, the script to generate the lat/long is automatically doing this over all the records in the database. Is there any posibility to do this only at the last added? ----> [Geolocation LONG/LAN in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543719/geolocation-long-lan-in-database)

Comment: @felix KlingThanks, Sorry it was my fault. Excuse me. now i get this error:  preg_split() [<a href='function.preg-split'>function.preg-split</a>]: No ending delimiter

Comment: `","` is not a regular expression, hence there is no need to use `preg_split`. Use `explode` instead. If you want to use a regular expression, I recommend to have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php, to get familiar with the syntax first.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. When i use this one, $coordinatesSplit = explode(",", $coordinates);, the geolocation fails.EDIT, everything is solved with the explode function but i have another question

Comment: Then ask a new question, don't change your question to something completely different... also try something before you ask.

Comment: @FelixKling here is the topic and the solution i tried    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543719/geolocation-long-lan-in-database

Comment: try this one: $coordinatesSplit = preg_split("/,/", $coordinates);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get simpler code with:

```
list($lat,$lng) = explode(",",$coordinates);
```

This directly assigns the result of `explode` into the two variables for you.

Comment: This will required after upgrading to PHP7

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in the comments, use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead:

```
$coordinatesSplit = explode(",", $coordinates);
```