# Split replacement Syntax

Tags: php, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP split alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813241/php-split-alternative)

What would be the command/syntax for replacing the depreciated split in the following syntax:

```
  $frags = split("\/", $the_image_src);
```

Comment: [$frags = explode("/",$the_image_src)](http://www.php.net/explode)

Comment: except minus the \ unless you use preg_split. escape is only necessary for regex based functions

Comment: when I change it the function does not work as before will look into why

Comment: were you expecting an array to be returned? That's what preg_split and explode return

Comment: I had tried explode("\/" ... which yielded different results.  Trick is to leave off the first \ as indicated by 2 answers above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The php docs for split suggest preg_split or explode, which has the same syntax

http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

See TIPS. Typically, deprecated functions will give alternatives

EDIT

```
preg_split("(/)", $the_image_src);
```

Comment: preg_split produces this error:  Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash.

Comment: right right, enclose with params... see edit to my post

Comment: I think the preg_split as indicated works or explode("/"... [note only single slash]

Answer (score 2):

If you are not matching a pattern (regexp) and only splitting on a string, you can use [explode](http://www.php.net/explode). It will work faster as it doesn't need to call the regex engine to interpret a pattern and match (even if the pattern is just a string, there is still overhead). If you want to match a regexp pattern as split normally would, you should use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/preg_split).

Comment: Note, with `explode`, you don't need the backslash, since you're splitting by a string rather than a regex.  It's a better idea all around, if you don't need the flexibility regexps offer, as you don't have to worry about escaping metacharacters the way you would with `preg_split`.