# Get value from a line containting key value seperated by : value can contain :

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP split alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813241/php-split-alternative)

I am a beginner in php, 
Basically I am trying to extrat value from a line 
the line format is key:value

The value may possibly contain :

So I want to divide it into two parts such that I get right and left side of first occurance of :

There is a function I have written because this will execute per line of a file

```
    /**
     * Returns value of the key if its available in line
     * example line 
     * somekey: someva:lue
     * @param type $line  pass full line
     * @param type $key pass the key
     * @return type  someva:lue
     */
    function extractValue($line, $key){
        $value = null;
        $value_array = split(":", $line);
        if(count($value_array)== 2)    
        {
            if($value_array[0] == $key)
               $value = $value_array[1];
        }
        return $value; 
    }
```

I just started coding it today in netbeans anf get the following warning that split is deprectaed etc

```
 Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\myprojects\PhpProject1\upload_log.php on line 92
```

I am not very familiar with php , could you suggest an alternate function ? basically I want the line into two parts key:value  want to get value given a line and key

Thanks for help,

Comment: You can use `explode(":", $line);` instead of `split(":", $line);`.

Comment: seriously people should just read the question before casting close votes... This is not a duplicate, even the title suggests that the question is **not** about split...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Simply](http://php.net/explode):

```
$value = explode(':', $line, 2);
```

2 is the maximum number of elements to get, which fits your problem.

Comment: +1 for `limit` use... should have thought...

Answer (score 4):

First off, use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) instead of [`split()`](http://php.net/split).

However, your code is good, you can also use:

```
function extractValue($line, $key)
{
    list($_key, $value) = explode(':', $line, 2);
    if ($_key == $key) {
        return $value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: if the value contains : in my case will it not exaplode too ?? can I not divide it into 2 parts ?? first occurance of :

Comment: The point is that `split()` is deprecated, `explode()` does the same task.

Comment: You first method has a problem I guess, would it not fail if line is like key:valu:e . It should return valu:e , can you look at it again ?

Answer (score 1):

If the value can contain the `:` symbol as well, it might be easier to use:

```
$value = ltrim(strstr($line, ":"), ":");
               ^^^^^^ Find the remainder of the string from the first : on
         ^^^^^ Get rid of the : at the start of the result
```

**Edit:** You can get the key in the same way:

```
$key = trim(strstr($line, ":", true));
                               ^^^^ Get everything before the first : symbol
```

See the manual on [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

I am trimming it in case there is some white-space before or after the key.

Comment: thanks, how do I match they key ?? I need to return null if key not found

Comment: @Jane You can use the same functions, see my edit. The `trim` part for the key is just in case your input is for example `key : value` (notice the spaces).

Comment: thanks for the answer much better than explode.. that's what I was looking for , not sure why php community under voted a question, ahh may be they do not like basic question :(

Comment: +1 for the help : Matthieu's answer seems more simpler , so I accept it. Thanks