# Non-Deprecated PHP Counterpart for 'split()'

Tags: php, html, hamachi

On a website I am making (but not yet hosted) I made a PHP chatbox. It works somewhat. I ran it on a localhost through xxamp. I can communicate with myself when I have 2 browsers open, but every 3 or so seconds, it says that the split() is deprecated in PHP. What is the nondep conterpart of split(). Also, I don't want to pay money for hosting, so can I "host" the website through Hamachi? I have hosted Minecraft servers on Hamachi, so I thought that I could host a website also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813241/php-split-alternative

Comment: Sorry for posting an already existing question. I did not realize that it has already been asked. Next time, I will search for my question before I ask it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Start:

```
$something = split(':', 'hello:world'); //deprecated
```

So:

```
$something = preg_split('/:/', 'hello:world');
```

Or:

```
$something = explode(':', 'hello:world');
```

Comment: He said he found answer to this one, and he's actually asking something else. lol.

Comment: Remaining question is something not really suitable for SO...  Can OP please answer his own question re. split (or better accept answer above) and close this?