# Separate time and day with different symbol from php data using split function

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-split

I had a series of data (class_time) store in php. And I wish to compare the day and time to prevent time collison when supervisor create the class. So I use the `list()` & `split()` functions to separate my data. The format of data is

> Fri, 11:00-13:00

And this is the code that I use to trace it.

```
while($row8=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result8){
    $preclasstime=$row8['class_time'];
    list($day, $starthrs,$startmin,$endhrs,$endmin) = split('[,:-:]', $preclasstime);

    if($day==$_POST['csday']){
        $numstarthrs=(int)$starthrs;
        $numstartmin=(int)$startmin;
        $tottimestart=($numstarthrs*100)+($numstartmin);

        $numendhrs=(int)$endhrs;
        $numendmin=(int)$endmin;
        $tottimeend=($numendhrs*100)+($numendmin);

        echo "$numendmin \n";
    }
```

However, after I execute it, it can obtain the `$day`, `$starthrs`, `$startmin` successfully, but when turn into `$endhrs`, `$endmin`, it cannot function well. It will skip one of the `$endhrs` and directly to the `$endmin`.

For example:

> $tottimestart=1100 but $tottimeend=0000, it will ignore the 13.
>   The answer should be 1300.
>   If another example such as: Fri, 11:00-13:30 , $tottimeend should be equal to 1330.

I don't know where the error which to cause it to skip one of my value.

Comment: Your accepted answer uses a shockingly poor regex pattern that is full of mistakes, please see my answer for the pattern you should be using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP split alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813241/php-split-alternative)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

> Alternatives to this function include: [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
$keywords = preg_split('/[\s,\s:\s-\s:\s]+/', "Fri, 11:00-13:30");
$day = $keywords[0];
$tottimestart = $keywords[1]*100 + $keywords[2];
$tottimeend = $keywords[3]*100 + $keywords[4];

echo $day."<br />";
echo $tottimestart."<br />";
echo $tottimeend."<br />";
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for reminding me of that, because I had search though the Internet, and don't know the different between these two. Thank you! Yours answer was also work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily like this ,if the format you have specified would follow always:

```
<?php 
$data = "Fri, 11:00-13:30";
list($day,$timingData) = explode(',', $data);
list($startTime,$endTime) = explode('-', $timingData);
$startTime = str_replace(':', '', $startTime);
$endTime = str_replace(':', '', $endTime);

echo "Day: $day <br/>";
echo "startTime: $startTime <br/>";
echo "endTime: $endTime";
?>
```

Output:

```
Day: Fri 
startTime: 1100 
endTime: 1330
```

Answer (score 1):

Use concatenator to join the strings before converting to interger

```
<?php 
$data = "Fri, 11:00-13:30";
list($day, $starthrs,$startmin,$endhrs,$endmin) = preg_split('[,|:|-]', $data);
echo 'Day: ' . $day;
echo '<br>Start: ' . (int)$tottimestart = $starthrs . $startmin;
echo '<br>End: ' . (int)$tottimesend = $endhrs . $endmin;
?>
```

Comment: Good. You don't need to convert to integer (int) if it's only for display purpose.

Comment: Because I want it for comparing value purpose, so I need to convert it to int.

Comment: This pattern would be more refined with a character class rather than alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this pattern to `preg_split()`:

```
/[ ,:-]+/
```

It will use one or more of the characters in the character class as the delimiter.  This ensures that the space that trails the comma is removed as well.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/60d96db3bd91c0ce4bd39fd457f56968d7f2efcb))

```
$row8['class_time']='Fri, 11:00-13:00';
var_export(preg_split('/[ ,:-]+/',$row8['class_time']));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Fri',
  1 => '11',
  2 => '00',
  3 => '13',
  4 => '00',
)
```

Of course, you can attach your `list()` call where I have `var_export()`.