# php regex search

Tags: php

I have this string:
`mr   (3_22)`

I want php to output that string to:
`(3_22)`

How can i do that with PHP? I need a sample code please

Comment: http://www.php.net/preg_match_all should help.

Comment: That's not a useful question title; being descriptive is important for future users who want to find similar topics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP split alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813241/php-split-alternative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$str ='mr (3_22) mrs (1_12) miss (2_4)';
$re ='';
if(preg_match_all('/(\([^\)]+\))/i', $str, $mt)){
  $re = implode('', $mt[0]);
}
echo $re; // (3_22)(1_12)(2_4)
```